# Raspberry pi as the default gateway in home network

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing

First I will describe my current network topology, then describe what goal I want to achieve.

Currently, my laptop is connected to a switch via ethernet cable, and the switch is connected via ethernet cable to my router, which is connected to my ISP. MY raspberry pi is also connected to the same switch via ethernet cable. Both my laptop and my pi have internet connectivity.

My goal is to route all traffic from my laptop through my raspberry pi. So I want the traffic to go

`laptop -> switch -> pi -> switch -> router -> internet`

I tried to accomplish this by enabling packet forwarding on the pi, and also making my default gateway on my laptop equal to the raspberry pis static ip address. When I try to ping google.com, what happens is I get nothing, no response, as if all the packets are being dropped silently by a firewall. I dont get "no route to host" or "gateway unreachable" errors, or anything like that. Also, I disabled the firewall on the pi, and my laptop has no firewall running.

Any advice on what might be going wrong? Or any extra steps I need to take?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/